# Process.Start with arguments not working

Tags: c#, process, system.diagnostics

I run this application in command line and get the desired results

```
 Helpdesk-02.exe /department it
```

but my C# code (below) appears to ignore the argument but launches the app without the command line switches

```
 ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
 psi.FileName = @"Y:\Helpdesk-02.exe";
 psi.Arguments = @"/department it";
 psi.UseShellExecute = true;
 Process.Start(psi).WaitForExit();
```

Comment: There's really no way we can test this since we don't have your executable.  Are you *sure* you get the desired results running it manually?

Comment: Can you debug "Helpdesk-02.exe" to check that the arguments are a) read and b) parsed correctly?

Comment: Does it work if you use the `Process.Start(String, String)` method to pass the args?

Comment: Sounds stupid, but have you tried it without the `@` character?  Also you may need `psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized;`

Comment: Removed the @ and it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

The `@` character is a special quoted string so it behaves differently than a standard string.  Essentially what was happening is the process was being started with what would look like this from the command line:

```
>  Helpdesk-02.exe "/department it"
```

Or one argument.  Removing the `@` symbol forces C# to interpret the string as expected:

```
> Helpdesk-02.exe /department it
```

A subtle, but critical difference.

The `@` operator was designed to make it easier to work with paths that have embedded spaces, backslashes, and other characters that have to be escaped in standard strings.  Essentially, it does the character escaping for you.  The two declarations are equivalent:

```
 string pathToExplorer = @"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe";
 string escaped = "\"C:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore.exe\"";
```

It's best to only use the `@` operator when you are working with paths to files, and use the normal way when dealing with the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for [ProcessStartInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.arguments%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) states:

> spaces are interpreted as a separator between multiple arguments. A
>   single argument that includes spaces must be surrounded by quotation
>   marks, but those quotation marks are not carried through to the target
>   application.

Comment: No, that's not it.